# Escape from open()

Tags: perl, escaping, code-injection

I am a newcomer to Perl, however not to programming in general. I have been looking for any hints how to escape from open() in Perl, but have not been lucky, and that is why I am asking here.

I have a:

```
$mailprog = '/usr/lib/sendmail';
open(MAIL,"|$mailprog -t");

read(STDIN, $buffer, 18);

print MAIL "To: xxx@xxx.xxx\n";
print MAIL "From: xxx@xxx.xxx\n";
print MAIL "Subject: xxx\n";
print MAIL $buffer;
close (MAIL);
```

Is there any way how I can shape the input into the $buffer so as to escape from sendmail ? The buffer input length is arbitrary. Input is totally under my control. Thanks a lot for any ideas !

Comment: What do you mean by "escape from sendmail"?

Comment: How about `close MAIL`?  It's unclear what you want to do.

Comment: At a guess, the `read` is blocking. Because otherwise I can't tell.

Comment: @choroba Based on the code-injection tag, I'd say he's looking for an exploit that will make sendmail run arbitrary code.

Comment: @kak, The bigger question here is, are you trying to build a botnet? :)

Comment: Note: You're missing the newline between the header and the body.

Comment: @choroba as ThisSuitIsBlackNot correctly observed im trying to find out if there is a way how to turn this into a RCE (or anything in that regard). And no im not building a botnet, it is just me looking at some really old Perl code and trying to see if anything in it can be leveraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man sendmail` says:

> By default, Postfix **sendmail**(1) reads a  message  from  standard  input
>          until  EOF  or  until  it  reads  a  line  with only a . character, and
>          arranges for delivery.  Postfix **sendmail**(1) relies on  the  **postdrop**(1)
>          command to create a queue file in the **maildrop** directory.

So you would want your input to contain the sequence `"\n.\n"` somewhere.

Comment: No need; the existing `close(MAIL)` will provide the necessary EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Only one sequence is special to `sendmail` once it starts reading the body: A line containing a single `.` signals the end of the input. (EOF does the same.)

That means that if your input contains a line that contains nothing but `.`, you need to escape it. The default transfer encoding doesn't provide a means of escape, so you will need to specifying a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` that avoids the issue (e.g. `base64`) or allows you to escape the period (e.g. `quote-printable`), and encode the content accordingly.

---

This brings us to the restrictions of the [content transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding) you choose adds.

The default content transfer encoding, `7bit`, requires lines of no more than 998 octets terminated by CRLF. Those lines may only contain octets in [1,127], and octets 10 and 13 may only appear as part of the line terminator.

If the content transfer encoding you chose isn't suitable to encode your input, you will need to choose a different one.

---

You really should be using something like [Email::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart) instead of working at such a low level.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was really informational. i have awarded the correct answer to the first person however. I still am not clear about what happens with the rest of my input that is after the . ? The sendmail exists and the open() closes ?